# what will be the behavior of program if we will print the structure variable itself

Tags: c, structure, printf, output

I am checking some output of a code in C. Code is:

```
main()
{
    struct temp 
    {
        int a;
        float b;
    }t;

    t.a = 5;
    t.b = 2.0;

    printf( "%d   %d    %f" , t, t.a ,t.b); // printing  5  0   0.0000000 ...why?? 
    printf( "%d   %f    %d" , t.a, t.b ,t); // printing  5  2.000000  5 
}
```

What will be the output of this program? What shall "t" will print?
If the behavior is undefined for this then is it given in some C standard that the behavior will be undefined.

Comment: Floats and integers use radically different bitformats, thats why you can't print an integer as a float and vice-versa. In fact, you can, but not get any sensible value out of it.

Comment: And pretty much printing it with `%d` will either result in the first member (if printable with %d itself), or undefined behaviour. If you want to print structs, either make a `printStruct(struct)` method of print with `%p` for pointer.

Comment: You should get warnings about that, and while some warnings can be dismissed many often tell you about you using undefined behavior. And undefined behavior is what you have here.

Comment: Do have in mind that you can print anything in C as an array...

Comment: @Shark %p isn't relevant, as the OP has no reason to print the address of t. And there is no way to write `printStruct` ... `struct` is not a valid type. And no, you can't "print anything in C as an array".

Comment: hm, i'm pretty sure this could work,
`double b; int* upper = (int*)((void*)&b[0]);` printing b would show the uppermost 4 bytes, It's a bitwise hack for sure, but works. And as far as I know - structs can have private methods, so a `printStruct` isn't out of line, and in case that they can't - writing a 'helper' method to print it wouldn't be far fetched either.  It was my understanding that the OP simply wants to print the structure and was struggling with how to best do it, and not understanding why the posted code works.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is an undefined behavior. Here is the corresponding part of the standard:

#### § 7.21.6 The `fprintf` function

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined. **If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.**

Comment: Thanks to all of you. @md5 thanks for sharing the standard's line.But if first argument is invalid then shall it ("undefined behvior") will make undefined for the next arguments also..? for ex.. in the first prinf the next 2 arguments are valid and correct then why garbage is coming out for them also.

Comment: @Dev: Even if the behavior is undefined only in a single expression, it makes the program wholly incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following code on Eclipse/Microsoft C compiler and duplicated your results without referencing just the `struct t`, other compilers might NOT behave the same way.

The `printf` statement will re-use variables to fill-out all of its % fmt definitions.  It looks like `t` is ignored and `t.a` and `t.b` get re-used.  This is why 0 and 0.0000 are printed, because `t.a` and `t.b` are paired with incorrect fmt definitions.

Per the prior answers, when a `printf` specification is incorrect, its results are undefined!

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    void main()
    {
       struct temp
        {
          int a;
          float b;
       } t;

       t.a = 5;
       t.b = 2.0;

       printf( "\n%d  %d    %f" , t.a ,t.b, t.a);  // printing  5  0   0.0000000
       printf( "\n%d   %f    %d" , t.a, t.b ,t.a); // printing  5  2.000000  5
     }
```